# Return elements of array to console sequentially (from getselectedItems method)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, javascript, client-object-model

I want to return each element of an array object to the console. The code below does return the object, but not sequentially as I would like. When I select Daffy Duck and Bugs Bunny from a view as selected items the array will return "undefinedDaffy DuckBugs Bunny" after the executeQuery fire off.

I'm not sure where the undefined is coming from. I of course want to return Daffy and Bugs individually to the console, however, after the promise resolves I get the following:

undefinedDaffy DuckBugs Bunny 
undefined

```
function callAccepted() {
    getSelected().done(function(objects, iLength) { 
    // Stuff
        for (var k = 0; k < iLength; k++) {
            console.log(objects[k]);
        }
    });
} // End callAccepted



// Get user information function
function getSelected() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function(){
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
        var SelectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
        var items = [];
        for (var i in SelectedItems) {
            var id = SelectedItems[i].id;
            var item = targetList.getItemById(id);
            clientContext.load(item, "Title");
            items.push(item);
        } 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){ 
                for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    var arrItems = [];
                    var itemObjects;
                    var itemLength = items.length;
                    itemObjects += items[j].get_item("Title");
                    arrItems.push(itemObjects);
                }
                dfd.resolve(arrItems, itemLength);
            },
            function(){ 
                dfd.reject(args.get_message());
            }
        );
    }); // End dfd
  return dfd.promise();
} // End getSelected
```

Comment: The example you refer to only shows one Context and does **not** do loops inside of loops. You introduce more **synchronous** loops and a second Context and then do **asynchronous** operations.. which ofcourse f*s up your **synchronous** loop, because unless you go for ES6 generator functions Loops can't deal with async code. So take 2 steps back, don't copy/paste examples unless you fully understand why they work, First learn JSOM & Async patterns with Promises, Recursion or whatever suits your need.

Comment: As Danny stated instead of doing a for loop inside a success function and then calling another jsom context from scratch inside of it, try using jquery promises to gather all the items you need, then return a promise and iterate through the array to write **afterwards** not during.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
// Grabs selected items from getSelected function and passes parameters to writeSelected function
function callAccepted() {
    getSelected().done(function(varObjects, iLength) { 
        for (var k in varObjects) {
            console.log(varObjects[k]);
        }

    }); // End getSelected
} // End callAccepted

// Grabs selected items, accepts input from callAccepted or callRejected functions
function getSelected() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function(){
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
        var SelectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
        var items = [];
        var arrItems = [];
        for (var i in SelectedItems) {
            var id = SelectedItems[i].id;
            var item = targetList.getItemById(id);
            clientContext.load(item, "Title");
            items.push(item);
        } // End for
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){ // Return to button click function
                var itemLength = 0;
                var itemObjects = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    itemObjects = items[j].get_item("Title");
                    itemLength += itemObjects;
                    arrItems.push(itemObjects);
                }
                dfd.resolve(arrItems, itemLength);
            },
            function(){ // Return to button click function
                dfd.reject(args.get_message());
            }
        ); // End ClientContext
    }); // End dfd
  return dfd.promise();
} // End getSelected
```